# Finally block on Using - Does it fire as in other contexts of Finally?

Tags: c#, using, finally, resource-cleanup

In some code I routinely work with (and have written a few times), code like the following has been used:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new FileWriter(".\SomeFile.txt"))
{
    // Perform file IO here...
}
finally
{
    sw.Close();
}
```

I'm familiar with try/catch/finally in C#...I know that context of finally works.  When I performed a google search on the terms "Finally Using", I could find no relevant matches.

Does this context of Finally work as I'm thinking, where upon the final command of the Using statement, the contents of the Finally block get executed?  Or do I (and the code base I'm working with) have this all wrong; is Finally restricted to Try/Catch?

Comment: I have never seen such a `using`/`finally` combination before. BTW, why calling `Close()` explicitly?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest, this is code I had seen from others originally.  I think the intent was that, for certain unmanaged resources (File IO, DB Connections) a cleanup needs to manually occur, because either A) a Dispose may not be defined, or B) a Dispose may not clean up everything, depending on how the author of that 'resource' chose to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is Finally restricted to Try/Catch?

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). A `finally` block *must* be preceded by a `try` block. Only `catch` is optional. Besides that you should read a bit about [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The `sw` variable you declare in the `using` block is not accessible outside that block.

Furthermore the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will dispose the `StreamWriter` (`FileWriter` is from Java ;-) as soon as the block goes out of scope (i.e. when the last instruction in that block is executed) so you don't have to discard or Close it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Finally always runs, but your code as it stands is mostly redundant.  The code:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new FileWriter(".\SomeFile.txt"))
 {
     // Perform file IO here...
 }
```

Is functionally equivalent to

```
 {
   StreamWriter sw = new FileWriter(".\SomeFile.txt");
    try {
       // Perform file IO here...
    }
    finally {
       ((IDisposable)sw).Dispose();
    }
 }
```

StreamWriter's Dispose() method implicitly calls Close().  However this should not be an error because user-defined Finallys run before system-implicit Finallys.

Comment: It's vice versa: `StreamWriter.Close()` calls its `Dispose` method.

Comment: Haha, you got me curious so I double checked in reflector.  Amusingly enough, we're both right.  `Dispose()` will call `this.stream.Close()` if it's required, while `Close()` will immediately call the `Dispose()`.  Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/BbcEqVwg

Answer (score 0):

Finally always works, whether or not there is an (uncaught) exception doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when a `using` is converted to [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) - .Net converts a `using` to a `try` (of sorts) anyway - And so it will still make sense in this context.

[See this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C)